# output of python script is duplicated when redirected to file

Tags: python, shell

I am excuting myfile.py and I want to redirect the output to a file, so I did this:

```
python2.5 myfile.py > affiche.txt
```

However, when I display affiche.txt, I see that the output has been duplicated.

Why are the messages duplicated in this file? the main of myfile.py contains this:

```
print "\n[BG:INFO] Automatic generation of the machine features\n"         
hostname = socket.gethostname()          
rep=DeletePoints(hostname)
if exists(rep)==False:  
    print "\n[BG:INFO] The directory of work is: ", rep, "\n"
```

Comment: Can you post your script?  The answer is probably there.

Comment: print "\n[BG:INFO] Automatic generation of the machine features\n"        

hostname = socket.gethostname()          

rep=DeletePoints(hostname)

if exists(rep)==False: 

 print "\n[BG:INFO] The directory of work is: ", rep, "\n"

Comment: Can you maybe add that to the question, not as a comment?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any issue that would double-print in the snippet you've posted, but it's also obviously not the entire file.  What else is there?

Comment: Rather than posting the code. Can you post the duplicated messages and the relating piece of code that prints those, _including_ possible recursive calls, or anything like that.

Comment: Are you sure that you haven't used `>>` (double) on the command line?

Comment: @J.F. Sebastian :yes I am sure it's only >

Comment: @mayhewr,faoretti : myfile contains too much lines of codes I just copy the begin and the twice messges in print are duplicated

Comment: In fact the execution of the code in myfile.py didn't end systematically but I do force it to be ended to see what is the content of affiche.txt

Comment: @nesskh: If myfile.py is too long, you need to strip it down to the simplest and shortest piece of code that still exhibits the same problem. See http://sscce.org/ for more. The chances of someone guessing what's wrong with your code, when we can't see your code, are pretty slim, and most people won't even try.